# Combine React Navigation 3.0 and JWT to determine initialRouteName based on auth state

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to make a normal App.js component integrated with JWT client to behave correctly when integrating React Navigator 3.0

Unfortunately I can only make work one or the other, not both. My issue is that React Navigator sort of hijacks App.js and determines the initial route instead of the usual App component render.

Here is my code so far:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createAppContainer,
         createBottomTabNavigator,
        } from 'react-navigation';
import Auth from './src/screens/Auth';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      jwt: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
     if (!this.state.jwt) {
      return (
        <Auth />
      );
    } else if (this.state.jwt) {
      return (
        <HomeScreen />
      );
    }
  }
}

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          }
        },
  Auth: { screen: Auth,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Auth',
          }
        },
  },
  { initialRouteName: App.state.jwt ? 'Home' : 'Auth' }
);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

As you can see, my issue is with this line:

```
{ initialRouteName: App.state.jwt ? 'Home' : 'Auth' }
```

How can I get the JWT state inside the TabNavigator component so I can define the correct initialRouteName?

`this.state.jwt` and `App.state.jwt` obviously do not work, and I tried (and failed) to pass the state to the TabNavigator object as a prop.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct method:

First you set get the Auth token and save its state in App.js. Then you pass the state as `screenProps` to the Navigation object:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      jwt: '',
      loading: true
    };
    this.newJWT = this.newJWT.bind(this);
    this.deleteJWT = deviceStorage.deleteJWT.bind(this);
    this.loadJWT = deviceStorage.loadJWT.bind(this);
    this.loadJWT();
  }

  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  };

  newJWT(jwt) {
    this.setState({
      jwt: jwt
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <Loading size={'large'} />
       );
    } else if (!this.state.jwt) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
          <TabNavigator screenProps={{setToken: this.newJWT }} />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

The navigation object passes it on to the screens that need it.

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
  Profile: {
    screen: props => <ProfileScreen {...props.screenProps} />,
    navigationOptions: {
        //tabBarLabel: 'Perfil',
        title: 'Header Title',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
      <Ionicons
        name={focused ? 'ios-person' : 'ios-person'} //TODO change to focused icon
        size={26}
        style={{ color: tintColor }}
      />
    ),
  }
  },
```

A you can see the props can passed on as ScreenProps and then read in the child component (screen) like this:

```
export default class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      email: '',
      username: '',
      phone: '',
      password: '',
      name: '',
      error: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const headers = {
      Authorization: this.props.jwt
    };
    api.get('/user')
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        email: response.data.data.attributes.email,
        phone: response.data.data.attributes.phone,
        username: response.data.data.attributes.username,
        name: response.data.data.attributes.name,
        loading: false
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.setState({
        error: 'Error retrieving data',
        loading: false
      });
    });
  }
```

I suppose this would be far simpler with Redux but I'm still learning that.

Answer (score 0):

May i ask that did you include login screen for authentication?

Comment: There are a couple of screens / components that handle auth based on if the user is trying to register or login. I used this: https://medium.com/@njwest/building-a-react-native-jwt-client-api-requests-and-asyncstorage-d1a20ab60cf4  . Worked like a charm

Comment: @Augusto I've been using that to implement the app but somehow after i create the navigation i couldn't login. When i tried to follow your method that without login screen, the app jump straight into the tab navigator, this is not what i wanted. Could you please help me fix this issue?

Comment: Sure. Just create a new question in Stack Overflow and I will post all my screens as an answer. I have it working just fine

Comment: @Augusto I've created the question at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53826920/could-not-navigate-to-another-screen-when-using-token-in-react-native