# Could not navigate to another screen when using token in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm currently developing an app using react native, right now my issue is that i couldn't navigate to main screen after login. Below is my code.

This is App.js (**EDITED**)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Loading } from './components/common/';
import TabNavigator from './screens/TabNavigator';
import AuthNavigator from './screens/AuthNavigator';
import MainNavigator from './screens/MainNavigator';
import deviceStorage from './services/deviceStorage.js';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  token: '',
  loading: true
}

this.newJWT = this.newJWT.bind(this);
this.deleteJWT = deviceStorage.deleteJWT.bind(this);
this.loadJWT = deviceStorage.loadJWT.bind(this);
this.loadJWT();

}

state = {
isLoadingComplete: false,
};

newJWT(token){
this.setState({
    token: token
});
}

render() {
if (this.state.loading) {
  return (
    <Loading size={'large'} />
   );
} else if (!this.state.token) {
  return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <AuthNavigator screenProps = {{setToken:this.newJWT}} />
        </View>
  );
} else if (this.state.token) {
  return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MainNavigator screenProps = {{token: this.state.token, 
deleteJWT:this.deleteJWT,}} />
        </View>
  );
}
}
}
```

This is Login.js (**EDITED-v2**)

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, KeyboardAvoidingView, 
TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import deviceStorage from '../services/deviceStorage';

class Login extends Component {

constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        error: '',
        loading: false
    };

    this.loginUser = this.loginUser.bind(this);
    this.onLoginFail = this.onLoginFail.bind(this);

}

loginUser() {
    const { username, password, password_confirmation } = this.state;

    this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });

    // NOTE Post to HTTPS only in production
    axios.post("http://192.168.1.201:8000/api/login",{
        username: username,
        password: password
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('response',response)
    deviceStorage.saveKey("token", response.data.token);
    console.log(response.data.token);
    this.props.newJWT(response.data.token);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    const status = error.response.status
    if (status === 401) {
        this.setState({ error: 'username or password not recognised.' });
    }
    this.onLoginFail();
    //console.log(error);
    //this.onLoginFail();
    });
}

onLoginFail() {
    this.setState({
        error: 'Login Failed',
        loading: false
    });
}

render() {
// other codes here
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
// other codes here
});
export { Login };
```

This is TabNavigator.js (**Added**)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Profile from '../screens/Profile';

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
{
Profile: {
screen: props => <Profile {...props.screenProps} />,
navigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
  <Ionicons
    name={focused ? 'ios-person' : 'ios-person'} //TODO change to focused 
icon
    size={30}
    style={{ color: tintColor }}
  />
),
}
},

},
{ initialRouteName: 'Profile',
 tabBarPosition: 'top',
 swipeEnabled: false,
 animationEnabled: true,
 lazy: true,
 tabBarOptions: {
  showLabel: false,
  showIcon: true,
  activeTintColor: 'orange',
  inactiveTintColor: 'orange',
  style: {
    backgroundColor: '#555',
  },
  indicatorStyle: {
    color: '#orange'
  }
}
}
);

const screenTitles = {
Profile: { title: 'Profiler' },
Home: { title: 'Home' },
};

TabNavigator.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
const headerTitle = screenTitles[routeName].title;
const tabBarVisible = false;
return {
headerTitle,
tabBarVisible
};
};

export default TabNavigator;
```

This is my AuthLoadingScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Login } from '../screens/Login';

class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
  showLogin: true
};
this.whichForm = this.whichForm.bind(this);
this.authSwitch = this.authSwitch.bind(this);
}

authSwitch() {
this.setState({
  showLogin: !this.state.showLogin
});
}

whichForm() {
if(this.state.showLogin){
  return(
    <Login newJWT={this.props.newJWT} authSwitch={this.authSwitch} />

  );
} else {

}
}

render() {
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {this.whichForm()}
  </View>
);
}
}

export default AuthLoadingScreen;

const styles = {
// style codes here
};
```

Lastly, this is my Profile.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Platform } from 
'react-native';
import { Button, Loading } from '../components/common/';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Profile extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
  loading: true,
  email: '',
  name: '',
  error: ''
}
}

componentDidMount(){
this.onLocationPressed();
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.props.token
};
axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://192.168.1.201:8000/api/user',
  headers: headers,
}).then((response) => {
  console.log('response',response)
  console.log('response2',this.props.token)
  this.setState({
    email: response.data.user.email,
    name: response.data.user.name,
    loading: false
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
  this.setState({
    error: 'Error retrieving data',
    loading: false
  });
});
}

render() {
const { container, emailText, errorText } = styles;
const { loading, email, name, error } = this.state;

if (loading){
  return(
    <View style={container}>
      <Loading size={'large'} />
    </View>
  )
} else {
    return(
      <View style={container}>
        <View>

            <Text style={emailText}>Your email: {email}</Text>
            <Text style={emailText}>Your name: {name}</Text>
        </View>

        <Button onPress={this.props.deleteJWT}>
          Log Out
        </Button>
      </View>
  );
}
}
}

const styles = {
// style codes here
};
```

I've fixed the previous problem that couldn't start the app. Right now i can see the login screen, but when i pressed login, there's a yellow box that indicates some problem. I've included the screenshot below.

[image: yellow box errors]

Lastly i've added the deviceStorage.js

**deviceStorage.js**

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const deviceStorage = {
async saveKey(key, valueToSave) {
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, valueToSave);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('AsyncStorage Error: ' + error.message);
}
},

async loadJWT() {
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
  if (value !== null) {
    this.setState({
      token: value,
      loading: false
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      loading: false
    });
  }

} catch (error) {
  console.log('AsyncStorage Error: ' + error.message);
}
},

async deleteJWT() {
try{
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem('token')
  .then(
    () => {
      this.setState({
        token: ''
      })
    }
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.log('AsyncStorage Error: ' + error.message);
}
}
};

export default deviceStorage;
```

**Before navigate**
[image]

**After navigate**
[image]

Comment: You forgot to export your Login component. You have `class Login extends Component {` but you did not have the final line `export { Login }` like in my code

Comment: I also recommend you have route names different than ScreenComponent names. For example `Login` route goes to `LoginScreen`. It will save you some headaches.

Comment: @Augusto i already included the export { Login } at the very bottom of the page. May i ask what do you mean by use different route names than ScreenComponent? By the way, i can see the login page but when i press the login button i couldn't login and there's a yellow box error, i dont know what does that mean and i have included the screenshot.

Comment: @Augusto I can pass the token on to the navigator after log in and can get the user details. But right now i have slight problem, when i press login the app displaying the yellow box error but after i re-launch the app, it jump into the main screen which is the tab navigator. So how do i able to fix the error?

Comment: Never mind the route names. It's not really important. Regarding the error, your error.response object is undefined. Check your API response by logging console.log(error) in the catch section of your login API call.

Comment: @Augusto I've put the console.log(error) but in the debug screen doesn't show any anything. If i remove the `const status = error.response.status
    if (status === 401) {
        this.setState({ error: 'username or password not recognised.' });
    }` the app won't show the yellow box error and the app still doesn't login, i had to re-launch the app in order to go into main page

Comment: I have uploaded my app here: https://github.com/augustosamame/react_native_jwt_demo_app. It's working fine so you should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: @Augusto Thank you! But i still couldn't figure out what causes the login problem.

Comment: nevermind, i just fixed the login problem it was in the App.js `<AuthNavigator screenProps = {{setToken:this.newJWT}} />` i change to `<AuthNavigator screenProps = {{newJWT:this.newJWT}} />`

Comment: @Augusto Sorry to bother you again. How do i navigate to a completely new screen that without the existing header bar and bottom navigation? I've attached the screenshot.

Comment: Hi. It's very hard to do it dynamically. I haven't been able to figure it out. If it's an entirely different screen you could try a different customized navigator for that screen. In my code notice how I have a MainNavigator which includes 2 different navigators, each with different settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my setup. It works like a charm. Sorry if it's a bit messy. I removed some stuff for clarity and I may have missed something:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Asset, Font, Icon } from 'expo';
import { ENDPOINT, USER_TYPE } from './src/config'
import { Loading } from './src/components/common/';
import deviceStorage from './src/services/deviceStorage.js';
import TabNavigator from './src/TabNavigator';
import AuthNavigator from './src/AuthNavigator';
import MainNavigator from './src/MainNavigator';
import globalStyles from './src/globalStyles';
import './ReactotronConfig';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      jwt: '',
      loading: true,
    };
    this.newJWT = this.newJWT.bind(this);
    this.deleteJWT = deviceStorage.deleteJWT.bind(this);
    this.loadJWT = deviceStorage.loadJWT.bind(this);
    this.loadJWT();
  }

  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  };

  newJWT(jwt) {
    this.setState({
      jwt: jwt
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <Loading size={'large'} />
       );
    } else if (!this.state.jwt) {
      //console.log(this.props, '<=== app.js');
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
          <AuthNavigator screenProps={{setToken: this.newJWT }} />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
          <MainNavigator
          screenProps={{ jwt: this.state.jwt,
                         deleteToken: this.deleteJWT,
                      }}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

AuthNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import AuthScreen from './screens/AuthScreen';

const AuthNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
  Auth: (props) => {
    return <AuthScreen {...props.screenProps} />;
  }
  },
  { initialRouteName: 'Auth',
    tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel: false,
      activeBackgroundColor: '#eee',
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AuthNavigator);
```

MainNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import TabNavigator from './TabNavigator';

  const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Main: TabNavigator },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Main',
      defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontSize: 20,
          textTransform: 'uppercase'
        }
      }
  });

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

TabNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import IconBadge from 'react-native-icon-badge';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';
import NotificationsScreen from './screens/NotificationsScreen';
import HomeStackNavigator from './HomeStackNavigator';
import CartStackNavigator from './CartStackNavigator';
import QuotesStackNavigator from './QuotesStackNavigator';
import InitialRoute from './InitialRoute';

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
  Profile: {
    screen: props => <ProfileScreen {...props.screenProps} />,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
      <Ionicons
        name={focused ? 'ios-person' : 'ios-person'} //TODO change to focused icon
        size={30}
        style={{ color: tintColor }}
      />
    ),
  }
  },
  Home: HomeStackNavigator,
  Quotes: QuotesStackNavigator,
  Notifications: { screen: props => <NotificationsScreen {...props.screenProps} />,
              navigationOptions: ({ screenProps }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
                  <IconBadge
                    MainElement={
                      <Ionicons
                        name={focused ? 'ios-notifications' : 'ios-notifications'}
                        size={30}
                        style={{ color: tintColor }}
                      />
                    }
                    BadgeElement={
                      <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>{screenProps.unreadMessagesCount}</Text>
                    }
                    IconBadgeStyle={{ width: 15,
                      height: 15,
                      position: 'absolute',
                      top: 1,
                      left: -6,
                      marginLeft: 15,
                      backgroundColor: 'red' }}
                    Hidden={screenProps.unreadMessagesCount === 0}
                  />

            )
          })

  },
  Cart: CartStackNavigator,
},
  { initialRouteName: 'Profile',
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: true,
    lazy: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel: false,
      showIcon: true,
      activeTintColor: 'orange',
      inactiveTintColor: 'orange',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#555',
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        color: '#orange'
      }
    }
  }
);

const screenTitles = {
   Profile: { title: 'Hola Maestro' },
   Home: { title: 'Selecciona la Categoría' },
   Quotes: { title: 'Mi Historial de Cotizaciones' },
   Notifications: { title: 'Notificaciones' },
   Cart: { title: 'Mi Pedido' },
};

TabNavigator.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
  const headerTitle = screenTitles[routeName].title;
  const tabBarVisible = false;
  return {
    headerTitle,
    tabBarVisible
  };
};

export default TabNavigator;
```

Login.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
//import Pusher from 'pusher-js/react-native';
import { ENDPOINT, USER_TYPE } from '../config'
import deviceStorage from '../services/deviceStorage';
import { Input, TextLink, Loading, Button } from './common';
import Header from '../components/Header';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      error: '',
      loading: false
    };
    this.pusher = null; // variable for storing the Pusher reference
    this.my_channel = null; // variable for storing the channel assigned to this user
    this.loginUser = this.loginUser.bind(this);
  }

  loginUser() {
    const { username, password, password_confirmation } = this.state;

    axios.post(`${ENDPOINT}/login`, {
      user: {
        login: username,
        password: password
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      deviceStorage.saveKey("id_token", response.headers.authorization);
      this.props.newJWT(response.headers.authorization);
      //this.setPusherData();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.onLoginFail();
    });
  }

  onLoginFail() {
    this.setState({
      error: 'Usuario o contraseña incorrecta',
      loading: false
    });
  }
  }

  render() {
    const { username, password, error, loading } = this.state;
    const { container, form, section, errorTextStyle, iconContainer, inputContainer, titleText } = styles;

    return (
      <View style={container}>
        <Header title="¡Bienvenido Amigo Maestro!" />
        <View style={form}>
          <ImageBackground source={require('./cemento-login.jpg')} style={{ flex: 1, marginBottom: 30 }}>
          <View style={{marginTop: 120}}>
            <Text style={titleText}>INICIAR SESIÓN</Text>
            <View style={section}>
              <View style={iconContainer}>
                <Ionicons
                  name={'ios-person'}
                  size={26}
                  style={{ color: '#fff', alignSelf: 'center' }}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={inputContainer}>
                <Input
                  placeholder="Usuario"
                  value={username}
                  onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
                />
              </View>
            </View>

          <View style={section}>
            <View style={iconContainer}>
              <Ionicons
                name={'ios-lock'}
                size={26}
                style={{ color: '#fff', alignSelf: 'center' }}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={inputContainer}>
              <Input
                secureTextEntry
                placeholder="Contraseña"
                value={password}
                onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
          </View>
          </ImageBackground>

        </View>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          behavior="padding"
          keyboardVerticalOffset={30}
        >
          <TextLink style={{ }} onPress={this.props.formSwitch}>
            Aún no estas registrado? Regístrate
          </TextLink>
          <TextLink style={{ }} onPress={this.props.forgotPassword}>
            Olvidaste tu contraseña?
          </TextLink>
          <Text style={errorTextStyle}>
            {error}
          </Text>

          {!loading ?
            <Button onPress={this.loginUser}>
              Ingresar
            </Button>
            :
            <Loading size={'large'} />}
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  form: {
    flex: 0.8
  },
  section: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    borderRadius: 3,
    marginTop: 10,
    height: 40,
    marginLeft: '10%',
    marginRight: '10%',
  },
  titleText: {
    color: '#fff',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  errorTextStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'red'
  },
  iconContainer: {
    flex: 0.1,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 3,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flex: 0.8,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    marginLeft: -70,
  }
});

export { Login };
```

Comment: Thanks @Augusto i seems to have some problem after implement. I have edited and added some code there

Answer (score 0):

Inside `App.js` you never change `loading` to `false` so the render method never gets to any of the other conditions. Once you have received the token you need to update state and change `loading`.